How to Retrieve First and Last Login Timestamps Per User Without Using Window Functions
I’m trying to get the first and last login timestamps for each user from a logins table that records a new timestamp each time a user logs in. Here’s the structure of my table:



user_id
login_timestamp




1
2024-11-01 08:30:00


1
2024-11-02 09:15:00


1
2024-11-03 07:45:00


2
2024-11-01 12:20:00


2
2024-11-02 08:50:00



I want to generate a result that includes the first and last login timestamps for each user, like this:



user_id
first_login
last_login




1
2024-11-01 08:30:00
2024-11-03 07:45:00


2
2024-11-01 12:20:00
2024-11-02 08:50:00



The catch is that I need to achieve this without using OVER (PARTITION BY). How can I do this?
I attempted a query using GROUP BY, but I'm not sure how to combine MIN and MAX functions in a way that gives both first_login and last_login in one row per user. Here’s what I have so far:
SELECT user_id, MIN(login_timestamp) AS first_login, MAX(login_timestamp) AS last_login
FROM logins
GROUP BY 1

This seems to work, but I’d like to confirm if this is the best approach, or if there’s a more efficient way to get both timestamps without using window functions.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Looks good, but try to avoid GROUP BY 1 and explicitly state the column you want to group by. This will help you if you decide to make changes to the query in the future.

okay, thank you so much

Try use index on(user_id,login_timestamp).

Your query is correct and efficient for getting the first and last login timestamps for each user without using window functions. The GROUP BY approach you used works well:
SELECT user_id, MIN(login_timestamp) AS first_login, MAX(login_timestamp) AS last_login
FROM logins
GROUP BY user_id;

This groups the data by user_id and uses MIN to get the first login and MAX for the last login. It's simple, effective, and performs well for most table sizes. Just make sure your login_timestamp column is indexed for better performance if your dataset is large.

okay, thank you
